# Customer Communities - Inactive Site Home Page

Tags: visualforce, community

I have a customer community with Tabs+VF template and not yet activated. I navigated to **Setup->Develop-->Sites** then select the community and set "Inactive Site Home Page"  to a VF page. Per the documentation, it should show the VF when the site inactive but it never shows the page. I verified debug logs and the it is going to **/apex/CommunitiesLanding** which is redirecting to login page though the community is inactive. Not sure why it is happening. Can you please give some insight and what is the significance of "Inactive Site Home Page" in terms of communities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your log-in controller to see what insight you might gain from that (what page does it direct you to?). As for the "inactive Site Home Page", if you're using the site for a Community, you don't want people logging into your site and being directed to the Community instead (or vice versa). The "site" should be used for one purpose only, either a SF "sites" or a community, but not both. Similarly, you want the log-in page to be used for one purpose only: to take you to your Community Home Page. Where it will take you is controlled by your log-in controller.